# Recommended Wireless Hardware

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, internet

I would like to buy a wireless card or usb adapter in order to be able to connect to my home wireless network from my desktop computer.

I heard that some cards are pain in Ubuntu, because of drivers.

Can you recommend some usb wireless adapters that can work in Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this [adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002RM08RE) for all my operating systems (Ubuntu, Windows 7 64-bit, Mac OSX) and it never failed me EVEN ONCE!

Comment: Thanks, I also read that http://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-TL-WN722N-150Mbps-Wireless-Adapter/dp/B002WBX9C6/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top works in Ubuntu without any drivers. You gave me idea to read reviews on amazon, thanks!